# "FoodHistoryControllerImp" not found. You need to call "Get.put(FoodHistoryControllerImp())"

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have the following code I cant figure out whats wrong even tho im using the same exact way in other pages and its working fine the Get injection is injected fine as you can see in the picture below but its not working it works fine when I hot reload but when visiting the page for the first time it doesn't

```
class FoodHistory extends GetView<FoodHistoryControllerImp> {
  const FoodHistory({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15,vertical: 10),
      height: Get.height / 2,
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          //separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(width: 10),
          itemCount: controller.foodHistory.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return FoodsEaten(
              i: index,
              foodHistoryModel:
                  FoodHistoryModel.fromJson(controller.foodHistory[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}

class FoodsEaten extends GetView<FoodControllerImp> {
  final FoodHistoryModel foodHistoryModel;
  final num? i;
  const FoodsEaten({Key? key, required this.foodHistoryModel, required this.i})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10,horizontal: 10),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      height: 140,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                      Text(
                          "${foodHistoryModel.foodNameEn}",
                          //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                    
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]),
            onTap: (){
            
            },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: error]
[image: injecting Get.put]
[image: Widget Call for the food listview]

[![After hot reload][4]][4]

AFTER HOT RELOAD
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/57ya0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`GetView` expects to find an already injected `GetxController`, it doesn't create a new one automatically, so you will need to inject it yourself by calling:

```
Get.put(FoodHistoryControllerImp());
```

anywhere you want in your code before using that `FoodHistory` widget.

Comment: its already injected second picture

Comment: you are literally missing up your app by calling it inside the build, everytime that build() is calles, it will be re injected again, try moving that code to the widget constructor initializer or by just declaring a variable holding it

Comment: My routing is deleting it everytime I leave the build 
[GETX] Instance "FoodControllerImp" has been created
[GETX] Instance "FoodControllerImp" has been initialized
when leaving the page
[GETX] "FoodControllerImp" onDelete() called
[GETX] "FoodControllerImp" deleted from memory

the problem was an error in the spelling of controller thanks for your help